# How to access json field by name stored in variable?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP variable created with json_decode.

The first field of the result has a name that i have stored in the variable.

So how i can access this field by name stored in variable?

I've tried:

`$json_decoded->{$item}`

but it returns null....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$v = "b";
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$d = json_decode($json);
echo $d->$v;
```

Another way

```
$v = "b";
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
$d = json_decode($json,true);
echo $d[$v];
```

Answer (score 1):

without making it a variable:

```
$json_decoded->item
```